Zero out loss for a certain pixel class in BCELossWithLogits
I am performing binary semantic segmentation on a dataset of pets (dogs and cats) each pixel has a class. There are 3 classes, foreground(1.0), background(0.0) and unclassified pixels(0.5020). I only interested in how good the model predicts foreground and background pixels. So my idea was to set the loss for "unclassified" pixels to 0. So that those pixels don't affect the gradient during backpropagation. In order to do so my idea is to create a mask that is 1.0 (true) for pixels of class foreground (1.0) and background (0.0) and is 0.0 (false) for pixels of class unclassified. Below you can see my implementation.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomBCEWithLogitsLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ignore_class_value=0.5020):
        super(CustomBCEWithLogitsLoss, self).__init__()
        # Initialize binary cross-entropy loss with logits
        self.bce_loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='none')
        # Store the ignore class value
        self.ignore_class_value = torch.tensor(ignore_class_value)

    def forward(self, outputs, labels):
        # Print unique values in the labels for debugging
        print("Unique labels:", torch.unique(labels))

        # Create a mask for ignoring unclassified pixels
        mask = (labels != self.ignore_class_value).float()
        print("Unique mask values:", torch.unique(mask))

        # Create binary labels for the foreground class (1.0)
        binary_labels = (labels == 1.0).float()

        # Calculate the loss
        loss = self.bce_loss(outputs, binary_labels)
        # Apply the mask to the loss
        loss = loss * mask
        # Normalize loss by the number of valid pixels
        loss = loss.sum() / mask.sum()

        return loss

The problem is that when running the code I get the following:
print(torch.unique(labels))
tensor([0.0000, 0.5020, 1.0000], device='cuda:0')
print(torch.unique(mask))
tensor([1.], device='cuda:0')

This not correct, since the label clearly contains class 0.0, so my mask should contain values of type 1.0 and 0.0.
I really do not understand why it does not work. I tried to use torch.isClose to check if the issus was related to floting point problems but that did not solve it either. Right now I'm stuck and are trying to understand what the problem is.

I took your class and passed torch.tensor([[0.0, 0.5020, 1.0, 0.0]]) as labelsand some random tensor as the predictions to it. It outputsUnique mask values: tensor([0., 1.])`. Can you try this and see what you get? I want to be able to reproduce your result.

I also tried to copy your code and provide labels = torch.tensor([0.5020, 0.000, 0.5020, 1.000, 0.5020, 0.000]) with random numbers as output. I get the same as @SachinHosmani
